# Extremely high current in super simple SMPS Flyback

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I'm building an SMPS in flyback topology. In order to do it, I use UC3845CB IC. In first step, I wanted to see if it even works at all with pulse transformer that I bought, made especially for flyback pulse power supply.
Below is the schematic for circuit that I've built. It is supplied from bench power supply with two outputs (+10V from output A and +20V from output B) connected via ground.

I connected all pins responsible for current and voltage control to ground in order to get simplest possible configuration.

[image]

When I turn only the +10V output, there is quite little current flow (0.01A).

But as soon as I turn on +20V, current on output A (not B!) rises dramatically (up to 3A), while current on output B is much lower (something like 0.3A). Strange thing is that IC does not heat up at all! And it is not burned either - when I turn off B output, I get 0.01A again on output A, and waveform on MOSFET gate is correct (50% PWM with 17kHz).

When I measure voltage on C2, it shows around 300V.

Also, when I turn ON only output B, there is no current flowing in the circuit.

Ratio of winding on the transformer is 56:14.

I'm totally confused, but again, I'm a total newbie regarding pulse power supplies. Anyone got a slightest idea what is going on?!

Edit: 
I changed the picture to better illustrate what is going on

Comment: Have you calculated the peak current in the primary of your coupled inductor to be sure you're not saturating it, given your switching frequency? With your feedback pin grounded you will be operating at max duty cycle meaning your secondary voltage can get very high maybe even breaking down your capacitor.

Comment: your oscillator is not free running, so you need to complete the loop by sending back the signal from a secondary winding to the feedback pin. That is why the ecessive current. when there is no oscillator, the driver transistor (next stage) goes into saturation. I remembered back in the vacuum tube television days  without the oscillator, the driver tube would get so hot, that it melted its glass envelope.

Comment: @JohnD Ok, so what you are suggesting is that I'm saturating primary side of the transformer? By the way, max duty cycle is only 50%. Can you suggest me any article on calculating peak current on primary side and saturation of the primary inductor? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @JohnD Is it necessary to know inductance of transformer's primary side in order to calculate the peak current? Also, how do you explain very high current fed into IC, while there is low current flowing on the supply attached to primary side of the transformer?

Comment: Also be mindful of the phase relation of the secondary to the feedback signal as the incorrect phase of the pulse will negatively effect the oscillator's operation. Also you might have to add snubbing capacitors if you notice rf spikes on the oscillator's output.

Comment: @drtechno So wha you say is that beacuse of no feedback loop, current going to internal driver transistor of the IC is as high as 3A? So how come current going through the transformer is only 0.5A?

Comment: because of the bias relation, the mosfet is not in depletion mode. but Andy did point out something that I should ask: what is your driver mosfet you are using? maybe you'll need to add a dampening diode across it.  but you are not having a self destruct issue with the output though (which would indicate that its needed) ... Granted, the oscillator needs to be running first

Comment: @drtechno MOSFET I'm using is STP6NK60ZFP. What do you mean by "because of the bias relation, the mosfet is not in depletion mode"? You mean that mosfet is not fully opened? Maybe I did pick pik up the wrong one...

Comment: you have to have oscillator action first. Otherwise, the output will be "off" this circuit runs in a matter that it switches its current 100% on and off with the oscillator signal.. alsoI'd put a reverse bias diode either across the mosfet or the transformer because I'm thinking the datasheet drew the zener across the device just to illustrate its construction. So that probably doesn't have a real dampening diode. If you don't have the oscillator running the predriver inside the chip goes into 100% conduction and sometimes can short completely out.

Comment: @drtechno Allright, I'll try it. But still I don't understand why there is this high current flowing through IC :(

Comment: I'll try again : This device meaning the devices are either in a state of 100% on or 100% off. The ic has an oscillator in it and a driver transistor.  When the feedback pin is low on the oscillator input causes the base of the driver transistor to be high which switches the transistor into saturation (110% on) this causes the output to be low, which stops conduction on the output transistor. Then when the feedback pin goes high, it causes the oscillator's output to go low causing the driver to turn off that causes the output pin to go high and the output transistor to saturate to 110%.

Comment: so when the driver transistor is on the output transistor is off, and when the driver transistor is off the output transistor is on... The driver is stuck on because the feedback pin hasn't seen a voltage yet to turn it off

Comment: you have to have a signal loop (in this case, you would use an output winding) to go back to the ic to create the on-off switching action of the oscillator as it is not a free running oscillator.

Comment: The UC3854 is a peak current mode controller.  It turns the switch on every cycle and turns it off when the peak switch current reaches the value programmed by the comp pin.  The peak current sense measures the current in the sense resistor on the source of the FET, but you have that input grounded along with your feedback pin.  If your "A" supply is taking lots of current I'm going to guess that your FET is damaged by gate punch-through or thermal avalanche damage.  You need to sort out the correct use of the device before you can calculate peak current etc.

Comment: @JohnD Allright, but if MOSFET was damaged, then when +20V output is off and +10V output is on, circuit should draw about 3A, right? But in this case it draws only 0.01A. How is that explainable? Plus I checked it using multimeter and it seems alright.

Comment: @drtechno When there is only +10V (no voltage on drain of the MOSFET) I can see 17kHz PWM signal on gate of the mosfet. According to what you write there should be no PWM signal, just 10V or 0V on the gate, right?

Comment: it would be a signal. I was stepping you through the operation so you would understand why ic pulls current when the oscillator is not working.

Comment: "when +20V output is off and +10V output is on, circuit should draw about 3A, right?"  No, that is way too much current.  It should draw much less, like maybe 0.01A.  If the gate is damaged, when you add the 20V supply you could get conduction through the gate causing the extra current draw.  Bottom line there's no way you should be seeing 3A on the supply to the IC.  Post some scope shots of the gate, the drain of the FET,  the clock oscillator and the voltage across the FET sense resistor and we should be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @JohnD Full quote would be "if MOSFET was damaged, then when +20V output is off and +10V output is on, circuit should draw about 3A, right?". Anyway,that's exactly what I meant, 3A is not normal:) When only +10V is ON, current draw is 0.01A. As soon as I turn ON +20V I get 3A going to+10V output of bench power supply and only 0.5 amperes going to +20V. 0.01A going to IC is normal, 3A definitely not. I will post scope screenshots from gate and oscillator as soon as I can:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly shrunken version of your circuit with letters A, B and C in red on it: -

[image]

- A - you HAVE (corrected, sorry) followed the correct dot notation for a flyback transformer. Good for you!
- B - you have no load connected and you'll need a minimum load most likely
- C - you have no mechanism to provide feedback control of output voltage to the chip such as this: -

[image]

I'm not ruling out that there are other problems but B and C are the glaring ones. I'm also unclear about what you are referring to when you mention letters A and B.

Comment: @Andyaka What I mean by letters A nad B are outputs of my bench power supply. What I found very strange is that On the power supply's output that provides supply for the IC, there is very high current (like 3A) while current going through the primary side of transformer is low (max 0.5A). How that can be explained?

Comment: @Andyaka Please also keep in mind that in my circuit, there is 56:14 ratio of the transformer (in your example, ratio is 4:50)

Comment: @EmKa that's irrelevant - you don't have output voltage feedback and the circuit I added does have it. That's the relevant bit, not the turns ratio. I have no idea about your power supply - please check it with a meter.

Comment: @Andyaka Power supply is OK, but what is strange is that it sends more current through the IC that through transformer as soon as I turn on both +10V and + 20V!

Comment: @EmKa without a flyback suppressor on the primary you may have unwiitingly destroyed the MOSFET with the knock-on effect that the UC3845 may be damaged.

Comment: @EmKa, please look at my comment under your question as to why there is excessive current through the driver circuit

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have found the mistake. As easy as it is... it was the lack of filtering at the input that was making indicators on lab benh powe supply going crazy. As soon as I add large 470uF capacitor on input, everything stabilized itself and now it is working fine:)